# Имя функции в скобках

Tags: c++, windows

Почему данный код не работает?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    min(1, 2);
    std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
}
```

А данный работает?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    min(1, 2);
    (std::numeric_limits<int>::max)();
}
```

Интересует больше второй пример. Что с точки зрения языка это означает?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что некоторые специалисты придумали поместить в Windows.h два define для min и max. Но перед компиляцией всегда работает препроцессор. Он видит max (о namespace он ничего не знает) и пытается найти два аргумента у него. А их там нет... И ругается. Когда появляются скобки, парсер препроцессора не видит скобок `()` не пытается сделать подстановку. Код стает "ожидаемый".

Второй вариант исправить проблему  - добавить в список define такой - `NOMINMAX`

Для любознательных. Внутри Windows.h есть такое

```
#ifndef NOMINMAX
#ifndef max
#define max(a,b)  (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif

#ifndef min
#define min(a,b)  (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#endif
#endif  /* NOMINMAX */
```

в Майкрософте проблему [знают](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/143208/prb-using-stl-in-windows-program-can-cause-min-max-conflicts), но трогать не  будут:).

Comment: получается скобки это хак для препроцессора?

Comment: обычный костыль. Когда то подобные макросы были выгодны - они компилировались в достаточно хороший код (компиляторы плохо умели инлайнить). Но я не понимаю, почему эти define втулили в windows.h.

Comment: с парсером препроцессора вроде как понятно, но почему скобки не мешают парсеру кода С++?

Comment: А с чего им мешать? Не мешают же для `int i = (((2)))*(((2)));` :) - в скобках - указатель на функцию. Вторые скобки - вызов функции по указателю...

Comment: (std::numeric_limits<int>::max) - это указатель на функцию?, () - а это вызов функции по указателю? правильно я понял?

Comment: @StanislavPetrov это просто имя функции в скобках. Имя функции часто может быть использовано вместо адреса функции.

Comment: @alexolut, Вы в этом уверены? Потому как если это не какой-то специфически описанный случай, который явно описан в стандарте, то это именно что указатель на функцию будет.

Comment: @ixSci я к тому, что всё это разные типы, а вызывать можно [как душе угодно](https://wandbox.org/permlink/inPawIYAmTRyqMnn).

Comment: @ixSci собственно происходит неявное преобразование: *A function designator is an expression that has function type. Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, a function designator with type “function returning type” is converted to an expression that has type “pointer to function returning type”.*

Comment: @alexolut, это ровно то, что я и сказал. Поэтому Stanislav понял всё правильно, а Вы зря его поправили.

Comment: @ixSci так `(std::numeric_limits<int>::max)` не указатель на функцию (в смысле *pointer*), а *designator*. Может быть, конечно, мне не стоило это называть и *именем*. Но я не знаю, как это на русском лучше будет употребить.

Comment: @alexolut, это указатель на функцию, потому что `std::numeric_limits<int>::max` здесь конвертируется в оный из-за того, что это rvalue выражение, в котором имя функции вырождается в указатель.

Comment: @ixSci [видимо](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QgTllFrYvpRatrpC), Вы правы.

Comment: В виндовс это вкорячили скорее всего в достандартные времена, а потом не убрали ради обратной совместимости. Так что заводите дефайн `NOMINMAX` на уровне проекта и не заморачивайтесь.